# How sql will rollback the data after minimum log operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate, bulk, transaction-log

I am reading about minimal logs and I have confused about this sentence.
Minimal logging involves logging only the information that is required to recover a transaction without supporting point-in-time recovery.
So, if I have done some minimum logging operation (for example, truncate) can I roll back the data? If yes, where does SQL stored them, and what is the difference between full logging operation. How actually SQL will retrieve the data?

Comment: If you are quoting articles/documents it's invaluable that you cite where that came from. Then we have the context that came from. I'm *guessing* you found it [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/minimal-logging)?

Comment: The source of quote is https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/sqlserver-logging/table-of-contents

Comment: Are you sure, @Jon ? I don't see a statement of  *"Minimal logging involves logging only the information that is required"* in the transcript of that course, however that ***exact*** phrase is found on the SSC article I linked to.